# Переопределить поля элемента

Tags: битрикс

Каким образом можно переопределить поле нового элемента при добавлении? Конкретно поле "символьный код".

Причем, значения поля "символьный код" берется из свойства элемента типа строка.

Элемент добавляется на странице через компонент `iblock.element.addform`.

Пытаюсь решить через событие `"OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd"`, но что-то не могу додуматься.

```
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd", Array("MyClass", "beforeElementAdd"));
class MyClass
{
    function beforeElementAdd(&$arFields)
    {
    CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');

    if($arFields['IBLOCK_ID']==9){

         $arFields["CODE"] = $arFields["PROPERTIES"]["symbolecode"]["VALUE"];

    }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, правильно так:

`$arFields["CODE"] = $arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"][#ID_свойства_symbolecode#];`

А лучше, распечатай данные в лог с помощью битриксовой ф-ии `AddMessage2Log`, чтобы увидеть структуру массива `$arFields`.

Comment: Ага, спасибо за ответ.